# Вылезла ошибка, не могу понять в чем суть

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Не могу понять в чем заключается суть ошибки

```py
def regural(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    user_id = message.chat.id
    cur.execute('SELECT regular FROM users WHERE user_id = ("%s")' % user_id)
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    mbc20017 = 'mbc20017'
    for card_rarity in users:
        if card_rarity[0] == 0:
            cur.execute('UPDATE users SET regular=? WHERE user_id=?', ('1', user_id))
            cur.execute('SELECT (image, card_name) FROM regular_card WHERE short_name=?', "mbc20017")
            cur.execute('UPDATE user_regular_card SET mbc20017=? WHERE user_id=?', user_id)
            cards = cur.fetchall()
            conn.commit()
            for card in cards:
                bot.send_photo(user_id, open(card[0], 'rb'), caption=f'Вам выпала карточка - <i>{card[1]}</i>', parse_mode='Html')
        elif card_rarity[0] == 1:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '')
            cur.execute('SELECT (image, card_name) FROM regular_card WHERE short_name=?', mbc20017)
            cur.execute('UPDATE user_regular_card SET mbc20017=? WHERE user_id=?', user_id)
            cards = cur.fetchall()
            conn.commit()
            for card in cards:
                bot.send_photo(user_id, open(card[0], 'rb'), caption=f'Вам выпала карточка - <i>{card[1]}</i>', parse_mode='Html')

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

```py
    cur.execute('SELECT (image, card_name) FROM regular_card WHERE short_name=?', "mbc20017")
sqlite3.OperationalError: row value misused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто уберите скобки, обособляющие столбцы, которые нужно выбрать:

```
cur.execute('SELECT image, card_name FROM regular_card WHERE short_name=?', "mbc20017")
```

[<kbd>Подробнее (enSO)</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123011/row-value-misused-error-in-sqlite-database)

---

Также у вас ошибка в параметре, так как функция считает строку как отдельные символы, поэтому попробуйте запихать строку в массив, а затем вызывать уже массив в качестве параметра.

[<kbd>Подробнее (CyberForum)</kbd>](https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-db/thread2522237.html)

---

То есть вот ваш окончательный код:

```
s=['mbc20017']
cur.execute('SELECT image, card_name FROM regular_card WHERE short_name=(?)', (s,))
```

Comment: cur.execute('SELECT image, card_name FROM regular_card WHERE short_name=?', mbc20017)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 8 supplied.

Comment: @panickx поправил:)

Comment: остается такая же ошибка

Comment: @panickx поправил снова, простите, не на то посмотрел

Comment: Теперь точно должно работать